# Failed to resolve: androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.5 Add Google Maven repository

Tags: java, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, android-glide

```
Failed to resolve: androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.5
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Show in Project Structure dialog
Show Details
```

The problem is not getting resolved even after adding the project structure to the Google Maven repository.
I used 12,14 version of glide dependency but i get same error in my case. anyone can hint me solution of this problem.
[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3M3m.png)
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZWdu.png)

I tried to fetch all row from database using php mysql localhost and retrofit2.0 to display multimedia files and textfields in android recyclerview.

Comment: Please and your gradle Build file and the Output of your failed build

Answer (score 0):

Add `mavenCentral()` in `settings.gradle` as

[image]

This might work.

Answer (score 0):

I added the below and it fixed the problem for me

- In this file: build.gradle.kts (module :app) add:

  implementation("androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.6")

Regards,